# ERROR TypeError: Constructor Map requires 'new' in ES5?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Code is:

```
export class ExtendedMap<T, U> extends Map {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    toggle(key: T, value: U) {
        if (this.has(key)) {
            super.delete(key);
        } else {
            super.set(key, value);
        }
    }

    has(key: T): boolean {
        return super.has(key);
    }
}
```

I get this error for ES5 compilation:

> ERROR TypeError: Constructor Map requires 'new'

I'm using it like this:

```
public registryLayers = new ExtendedMap<number, any>();
```

Snippet (without TypeScript parts commented out):

```js
/*export*/ class ExtendedMap/*<T, U>*/ extends Map {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    toggle(key/*: T*/, value/*: U*/) {
        if (this.has(key)) {
            super.delete(key);
        } else {
            super.set(key, value);
        }
    }

    has(key/*: T*/)/*: boolean*/ {
        return super.has(key);
    }
}
/*public*/ registryLayers = new ExtendedMap/*<number, any>*/();
console.log("Worked without error");
```

Comment: That is all I have I posted in question! I have found this information:

`Just change your compilerOptions inside tsconfig.json
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es6",
}

new Map operator is a ES6 feature so you need to target your exported js to ES 6 Syntax`

Comment: I chaged on es5 target, it works, but  I need es5

Comment: I was just about to point out that `Map` wasn't in ES5. Also note that there's no point to either the constructor or the `has` override in your code. You can inherit both, since neither does anything new. It would also probably be best to use `this` rather than `super` in `toggle`.

Comment: Then you'll need a polyfill, because ES5 didn't have `Map`.

Comment: Could you share an sample how to extens properly, on the words I did not get you

Comment: FWIW here's a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4FEQ2AOwBNhCBZFMAHgBUAaOAVQD45Q8jNyq7GWBvALAAoAPQi4ASTiEI+AOTwA1vggB3OAEsAZnBgALYGmBwUUY-mAJDaUwE84DuAD0Xr4cMdwxcAHIQ4FiRwWtBwAAYIsmgwUACuCDDQYfS2ELGIKPhwsUa6BtLAWiixSPCyxmga+FZwqbFQaB6O3jKG8vAyJvi2+lUA5nBoYJYaKEjuQp7eElm9mAjowPQ5xmFzYXBQKPrAUHmZ4Wixw1AbqgZZC0hI-eHESMB4G5mEh49hTQ6JfX0PABSKYC2ABccB4ADcxrFgKCGABKOCCSaeRzaOB-OYAOj06ABQLhCKRKOJeQ0aEx90ewDxtjhAG5PiiAL6sJC5IkkzxYowwGn0SFIaH0xmeJmMsVCRnePwBYBBEJ7MI4tAbSrVYx1PYQcG7KAaYjSfXtEyEV6ZHp6frCCXCSL4aJwAC2FDgAF5ZeocOxiGQKJRonr8H16PhYo6AEa7Jh-elAA)

Comment: Are you sure you want to do it? I mean, it is better to make your own data structure and use Map under the hood. I don't think it is ok to extend built in data structures.

Comment: T.J. Crowder - thank you, I got your mind

Comment: @captain-yossarian - It's fine to extend `Map` provided you don't change the semantics of the built-in methods (you *can* do that if you want, but violating the Liskov Substitution Principle is likely to bite you :-) ). In fact, `Map` even provides a `Symbol.species` function to help with subclasses. I mean, `class X` extends `Object`... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder wow! I mean - WOOOOOW. I have never used `Symbol.species before`. I should have follow your answers a long time ago

Comment: @captain-yossarian - **LOL** You know I come in book form now, too, right? ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, I know, I saw it on your blog. This, defenitely, will be my next book. For now I have two others I did not finished yet )). I like that you went deeper into JS specification

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TypeScript should be complaining about `Map` if you're targeting ES5 (it does [in this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4FEQ2AOwBNhCBZFMAHgBUAaOAVQD45Q8jNyw4BvAWABQcYYgj40MKAFcEMaAAoAlL0Ei1cNFLDAoSgNyqRAX0GHhcgOYWkweQGtgATwBccOnABuKJFOCuGyvxC6sIAlgBmcPIwABahaAB0Mej2ToqBZiEimtpQCcQ2eKmOigbBIUasSGjAKuVZwjk6CTUwxfRePsClmWom9f2ZyWjFrtSKrgBGEBA2KPh1DVDAMFJQC015w8U9A4JGQA)).

If you ignore that error from TypeScript and then run the code that TypeScript generates in a modern(ish) JavaScript engine, the problem is that the code TypeScript created is trying to call `Map` like an old-style constructor function. When you configure TypeScript to emit ES5 code, it doesn't emit `class` constructs because ES5 didn't have them. Instead, it emits constructor function syntax, and in your `ExtendedMap` constructor, it tries to call `Map` like this:

```
return _super.call(this) || this; // Where `_super` is set to `Map`
```

But in a modern environment, `Map` is defined as a `class` constructor and cannot be called that way, resulting in the error you're getting.

If you need your code to run in an ES5 environment, you need to include a `Map` polyfill (since `Map` didn't exist in ES5) that is written to be compatible with an ES5 environment so that `Map` can be called via `.call` as above. And if your code is running in a modern(ish) environment that already has `Map`, you'll still need to include the polyfill because of the way it gets called.